# PHP - Concatenating two variables

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

I'm a newbie stumped on the following. If I'm including an external file on a page that contains the following variable:

```
$blurb_78 = "Lorem ipsum dolor.";
```

How can I echo $blurb_78 on the local page?
(where the `78` part is a generated article ID set to a variable labeled, `$id`)

The following doesn't work:

```
echo $blurb_.$id;
```

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: The phrasing is creating some confusion: do you want the output to be "$blurb_78" or "Lorem ipsum dolor."? I answered for the former; many for the latter.

Answer (score 7):

I think you mean a variable variable name like it is mentioned at the [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) page on the PHP site. In your case this should work fine:

```
echo ${'blurb_'.$id};
```

But I highly doubt your approach on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try making an array:

```
$blurb = array();

$blurb[78] = "Lorem ipsum";

echo $blurb[$id];
```

Comment: OP wanted to output the vas's *name*.

Comment: ... And I was wrong. I'm going to upvote a random other question of yours, since I downvoted this more than 7 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an associative array instead of variables in your case.

Check this article in PHP official documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer:

```
 echo '$blurb_'.$id;
```

Still, an associative array is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${'blurb_'.$id};
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/Hb6HrINN)

Read more on the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) article.

Comment: Not really. Op wanted to output the string "$blurb_78" with the "78" part given as a variable.

Comment: @cbrandolino Huh? What is mine doing? I have even linked to a demo page so you can see how it's working. Edit: I see what you meant. I don't think OP was that PHP illiterate.

Comment: It's echoing the var's value, while I thought OP wanted its name to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$blurb_78 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor.';
$id = 78;
echo ${'blurb_'.$id};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for concatenating two variables:

```
echo ${'blurb_'.$id}
```