# how to concatinate two variables

Tags: php

I have table that contain data

```
<td><?php echo $users->aa_0?></td
<td><?php echo $users->aa_1?></td>
<td><?php echo $users->aa_2?></td>
<td><?php echo $users->aa_3?></td>
```

when i'm applying static value to above code, it is working
But when i'm changing it to dynamic the below code is not working...
kindly help me

```
<?php foreach ($get_users as $users) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $users->aa_.$i?></td>
        <?php  ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257505/dynamic-variable-names-in-php)

Comment: Although this looks like a perfect use case for arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Concatenating two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648688/php-concatenating-two-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Basically

> $users->{"aa_$i"}

But as JJ said, you should use arrays, like

> $users->aa[$i]